# How do I save a DataUrl Image to disk in .net?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, data-url

I have an image in a DataUrl and I need to save it to disk.  Do I just use the normal "[save from the web url](http://geeknotes.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/saving-a-possibly-binary-file-from-a-url-in-c/)" style or is there an easier way to do this without involving the HttpWebRequest stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpRequest will not work with a `data:` URI.

Instead, you can parse out the actual data, then call `File.WriteAllBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(data))`

Comment: `WebRequest` doesn't support data: by default, but [you can configure it for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779498/41071).