# Getting exception while using itextsharp to convert from html to pdf in web api

Tags: pdf, asp.net-web-api, itext, uri

List item

I am getting `"the uri prefix is not recognized itextsharp"`

Exception. Following the method of my web api controller. which receives the html data and converting it to pdf.

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPDF(long estimationId)
    {  

   HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);      
         try
        {
//Method fetch the data for estimationId and convert that to HTML
            string html = objRepository.GetHTML(estimationId);

            //Create PDF
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
            document.SetMargins(20.0F, 20.0F, document.TopMargin + 20, document.BottomMargin);
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            document.Open();
            StringReader strRdr = new StringReader(html);
            var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(strRdr, null);
            foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
                document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            writer.Flush();
           // document.Close();
            output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(output.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLog.GetDefault(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Log(new Error(e));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Exception occurred at line

```
   var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(strRdr, null);
```

Any help please.

Comment: It was Image path were not resolving inside the texts body...Resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to inspect your HTML. The exception isn't really an iTextSharp exception but instead comes from iTextSharp asking the .Net framework to download a remote resource via `System.Net.WebRequest`. One way or another you've got a URL that doesn't start with `http` or `https` (or `file` or `ftp`), often this is a base64 encoded image. You can reproduce this message by doing this:

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("data:image/png;base64");
req.GetResponse();
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The URI prefix is not recognized.

If you had a protocol-less/protocol relative URL you'd get a slightly different message:

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("//gerp");
req.GetResponse();
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The UNC path should be of the form \server\share.

You'll need to either change the HTML to use only the support protocols or possibly [register your own prefix with the system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779498/231316).

Comment: Thanks, In my HTML there is image path, which were not resolved.