# Input is not a valid base64 string exception occurred when parsing HTML string in C#

Tags: c#, itext, html-parser

I am parsing an HTML string using HTMLworker in C#.
these are the libaries I am using,

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

This is how I am parsing the data:

```
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);    
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);        
        sb1.Append(@"<img src='data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAX1SURBVHhe7ZJBjuQ4DAT7/5+eHd0CBmOWhGXaDTGAuKSyRKvAnz/D0cwCHM4swOHMAhzOLMDhzAIczizA4cwCHM4swOHMAhzOLMDhzAIczizA4cwCHM4swOHMAhzOLMDhzAIczizA4cwCHM4swOHMAhzOLMDhzAIczizA4cwCHE7bAvz8/GyXWE7YyZgh+t1dO5kF+IcZot/dtZNZgH+YIfrdXTt5ZQHukLmHHXoHu8fyKrvuqdI2bdcDM/ewQ+9g91heZdc9Vdqm7Xpg5h526B3sHsur7LqnSts0eyBzk1huWJ85JdH5kmRyk1j+NG3T7IHMTWK5YX3mlETnS5LJTWL507RNswcyN4nlhvWZUxKdL0kmN4nlT9M2zR7I3CSWV+E9lETnS5LJTWL507RNswcyN4nlVXgPJdH5kmRyk1j+NG3T7IHMTWJ5Fd5DSXS+JJncJJY/Tds0eyBzk1hOrJPJKbmTm8Typ2mbZg9kbhLLiXUyOSV3cpNY/jRt0+yBzE1iObFOJqfkTm4Sy5+mbdquB1bvsb7lhvUtr7Lrnipt03Y9sHqP9S03rG95lV33VGmbtuuB1Xusb7lhfcur7LqnSts0PnCX5Av5LjtpmxY99K7kC/kuO2mbFj30ruQL+S476Z32IPYHMqfEcpLp/EZmAf5iOcl0fiOzAH+xnGQ6v5G21/APpCQ6XxLLCTsZSXS+NDKdDLvuqdI2jQ+kJDpfEssJOxlJdL40Mp0Mu+6p0jaND6QkOl8Sywk7GUl0vjQynQy77qnSO+1/4J9ADetYTqzDnGaIfnf1a3zqi6I/bGlYx3JiHeY0Q/S7q1/jU18U/WFLwzqWE+swpxmi3139Gq9/UfQnLUl0viSZnJLo/OrTdM4ivdMC+HBKovMlyeSUROdXn6ZzFumdFsCHUxKdL0kmpyQ6v/o0nbNI77QAPtzMEP3uXxpR92qV6I7lF5gFuBB1r1aJ7lh+gVmAC1H3apXojuUXeOUrMn8CO6aR6WTI3LOr8xavfFHmD2HHNDKdDJl7dnXe4pUvqv6xppHpZMjcs6vzFm1fxD+BZrC+5Qb7uzSi7vJrtH1R9GcsM1jfcoP9XRpRd/k12r4o+jOWGaxvucH+Lo2ou/wabV8U/RlXjai7JNH50oi6S5LJTSPqXu2kbVr00KtG1F2S6HxpRN0lyeSmEXWvdtI2LXroVSPqLkl0vjSi7pJkctOIulc7aZtmD2SekVj+BezbqvnTtE2zBzLPSCz/AvZt1fxp2qbZA5lnJJZ/Afu2av40bdPsgZYb1md+RxKdP+VbtE22x1puWJ/5HUl0/pRv0TbZHmu5YX3mdyTR+VO+xXuTN2N/puWG9S032KckOl920jvtQewPtNywvuUG+5RE58tOeqc9iP2BlhvWt9xgn5LofNlJ27TooXetYr+1nFinmhvV/i7apvGBu6xiv7WcWKeaG9X+Ltqm8YG7rGK/tZxYp5ob1f4u2qbtemD1Huszr5oh+t2SWN5J2+Rdj63eY33mVTNEv1sSyztpm7zrsdV7rM+8aobod0tieSdtk+2xzE1yJzdJdP6UX6DtK+zhzE1yJzdJdP6UX6DtK+zhzE1yJzdJdP6UX6DtK+zhzE2SyTMaUXdJovOrRtS92knbNHsgc5Nk8oxG1F2S6PyqEXWvdtI2zR7I3CSZPKMRdZckOr9qRN2rnbRNswcyN4nlGaq/tX4mp0bUXXbSNs0eyNwklmeo/tb6mZwaUXfZSds0eyBzk1ieofpb62dyakTdZSdt03Y90O6p5ob1qzlhJ2MnbdN2PdDuqeaG9as5YSdjJ23Tdj3Q7qnmhvWrOWEnYydt06KH3pVUc8P6mdzMUO3vom0aH7hLUs0N62dyM0O1v4u2aXzgLkk1N6yfyc0M1f4ueqcNn2MW4HBmAQ5nFuBwZgEOZxbgcGYBDmcW4HBmAQ5nFuBwZgEOZxbgcGYBDmcW4HBmAQ5nFuBwZgEOZxbgcGYBDmcW4HBmAQ5nFuBwZgEOZxbgcGYBDmcW4HBmAY7mz5//AJt02kiYlE4XAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' runat='server' alt='myimage'>");
    
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("data", new DataWebRequestFactory()); // this is to register new prefix
using (StringReader srb = new StringReader(sb1.ToString()))
    {
       htmlparser.Parse(srb); //here I am getting an exception  
    }
```

Here I register new prefix 'data' to get rid of the 'uri prefix not recognized' exception, as explained here: [Getting exception while using itextsharp to convert from html to pdf in web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948980/getting-exception-while-using-itextsharp-to-convert-from-html-to-pdf-in-web-api)

But now I am getting a new exception that 'Input is not a valid base64 string'.
Please suggest how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean you want to convert html(with base64 image) to pdf?

Comment: Yes. I am binding my html code in C# as a string. I am using HTMLWorker to parse that code in PDF.

Comment: Please be aware that the `charset=utf-8` does not make sense here - a PNG image does not have a charset. Thus, this might give rise to errors. Also, you should remove the space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove everything in front of and including the first comma.

So change your

```
sb1.Append(@"<img src='data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARn.....);
```

to

```
sb1.Append(@"<img src='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARn.....);
```

Comment: I tried this, it throws an exception that  "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters"

Comment: @itachi maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434206/visual-studio-unknown-build-error-the-fully-qualified-name-must-be-less-than-26